# No such element even use explicit wait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with ChromeDriver to crawl images. To speed up the progress, I execute javascript `window.stop()` to stop loading the whole page as soon as the elements of interest are loaded. I ran the same code several times but get different outcomes (sometimes the `NoSuchElementException` occurred, sometimes not).

Could anybody explain what's wrong with my code? Here is my sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


def get_driver(quick_load=True):
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chromeOptions.add_argument('headless')
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    if quick_load:
        capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa,
                                    chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    return driver, wait

url = [
    "https://www.redbubble.com/people/captainkita/works/27361999-no-words?grid_pos=2&p=lightweight-hoodie&rbs=84d3442a-6f22-4dc1-980d-9a707104c791&ref=shop_grid",
    "https://www.redbubble.com/people/zeeteesapparel/works/27338911-game-of-thrones-waiting-for-a-bastard-with-direwolf?grid_pos=44&p=t-shirt&rbs=337dcf4c-3ff9-4507-9cbd-c6e80f78d022&ref=shop_grid&style=vneck",
    "https://www.redbubble.com/people/zeeteesapparel/works/27338911-game-of-thrones-waiting-for-a-bastard-with-direwolf?grid_pos=44&p=t-shirt&rbs=337dcf4c-3ff9-4507-9cbd-c6e80f78d022&ref=shop_grid&style=vneck"
]

driver, wait = get_driver()

for u in url:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('%s');" % u)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="image"]')))
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    print "Stopped window"
    images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[type="image"]')
    print len(images)
    candidates = [t for t in images if "750x1000" in t.get_attribute('src')]
    print candidates[-1].get_attribute('src')
    # driver.execute_script("window.close();")
    # driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Executed a few times, works for me perfectly. Could you post a traceback with the error you are getting? Don't see a place where it can happen naturally in this code. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I get error in the line images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[type="image"]'). I drop the headless option to see how Chrome works and see strange things. At the moment the stopping script is executed, Chrome stops loading then suddenly lose everything it has loaded so far, which triggers the NoSuchElement exception to happen in following lines.